# TypeError: 'JpegImageFile' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask

I'm actually trying to link my ml model(inception) with flask . The 
output is binary (0 or 1). The image format is jpg or jpeg (both). I have tried with .stream while asking for input. Actually the model doesnt take image when  file = Image.open(request.files['file'].stream).

```
 flask code :
import os
from try1 import obj12
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, 
send_from_directory,send_file
from PIL import Image
import io
import cv2


    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
     def index():
        return render_template('test.html')





@app.route("/upload", methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    image = Image.open(file)
    count = obj2(image)
    print (count)
    return (count)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(debug=True)

  html code : 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload</title>
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="upload-form" action="{{ url_for('upload') }}" method="POST" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <strong>Files:</strong><br>
    <input id="file-picker" type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" 
     multiple>
     <div id="msg"></div>
     <input type="submit" value="Upload!" id="upload-button">
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Just want to pass my image in that model.

Comment: Please split the code provided into Python code and Jinja template and correctly indent the Python code. Also, provide all relevant code (e.g. you use `count = obj2(image)` but `obj2` is not known to us). Last, please provide complete traceback, not just the single error message.

Comment: obj2 is my function from try1.py file . i have basically made a function which has my inception model and i'm trying to pass my image to that file